# Genesis Balances

Tags: contract, account, address, block, genesis

I found out that the genesis balances of each account are present in https://tezos.foundation/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/5223213-genesis.txt .

Couple of Questions:

1) I see Bootstrap Contracts have a respective delegate address mentioned there along with the initial contract balance. What's the respective Contract address?

2) Why do all the `tz3` addresses in `Bootstrap accounts` start only with 0.000001 XTZ balance?

3) What's the difference between `Bootstrap accounts` and addresses under `Commitments`?

4) How do I convert a commitment address into a regular tz address? (Eg: `btz1LKddKfC9cEitY8Q5bMnGS9yj9uPWnmX68` shows up as `tz1b9goTMbVfCuVGfuA8UiaSxtrY3of4CZM9` in https://tzstats.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Here they are

`$ ./tezos-client rpc get  /chains/main/blocks/1/context/contracts | grep KT1`

```
  "KT1WPEis2WhAc2FciM2tZVn8qe6pCBe9HkDp",
  "KT1W148mcjmfvr9J2RvWcGHxsAFApq9mcfgT",
  "KT1VvXEpeBpreAVpfp4V8ZujqWu2gVykwXBJ",
  "KT1VsSxSXUkgw6zkBGgUuDXXuJs9ToPqkrCg",
  "KT1Um7ieBEytZtumecLqGeL56iY6BuWoBgio",
  "KT1TzamC1SCj68ia2E4q2GWZeT24yRHvUZay",
  "KT1TcAHw5gpejyemwRtdNyFKGBLc4qwA5gtw",
  "KT1THsDNgHtN56ew9VVCAUWnqPC81pqAxCEp",
  "KT1SLWhfqPtQq7f4zLomh8BNgDeprF9B6d2M",
  "KT1RUT25eGgo9KKWXfLhj1xYjghAY1iZ2don",
  "KT1QuofAgnsWffHzLA7D78rxytJruGHDe7XG",
  "KT1Q1kfbvzteafLvnGz92DGvkdypXfTGfEA3",
  "KT1PDAELuX7CypUHinUgFgGFskKs7ytwh5Vw",
  "KT1Msatnmdy24sQt6knzpALs4tvHfSPPduA2",
  "KT1LZFMGrdnPjRLsCZ1aEDUAF5myA5Eo4rQe",
  "KT1LQ99RfGcmFe98PiBcGXuyjBkWzAcoXXhW",
  "KT1Kfbk3B6NYPCPohPBDU3Hxf5Xeyy9PdkNp",
  "KT1KRyTaxCAM3YRquifEe29BDbUKNhJ6hdtx",
  "KT1JW6PwhfaEJu6U3ENsxUeja48AdtqSoekd",
  "KT1HvwFnXteMbphi7mfPDhCWkZSDvXEz8iyv",
  "KT1Gow8VzXZx3Akn5kvjACqnjnyYBxQpzSKr",
  "KT1FuFDZGdw86p6krdBUKoZfEMkcUmezqX5o",
  "KT1FN5fcNNcgieGjzxbVEPWUpJGwZEpzNGA8",
  "KT1FL3C6t9Lyfskyb6rQrCRQTnf7M9t587VM",
  "KT1EWLAQGPMF2uhtVRPaCH2vtFVN36Njdr6z",
  "KT1DnfT4hfikoMY3uiPE9mQV4y3Xweramb2k",
  "KT1D5NmtDtgCwPxYNb2ZK2But6dhNLs1T1bV",
  "KT1Cz7TyVFvHxXpxLS57RFePrhTGisUpPhvD",
  "KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy",
  "KT1CM1g1o9RKDdtDKgcBWE59X2KgTc2TcYtC",
  "KT1A56dh8ivKNvLiLVkjYPyudmnY2Ti5Sba3",
  "KT19xDbLsvQKnp9xqfDNPWJbKJJmV93dHDUa",
```

2) addresses need a minimum balance to exist, 1 mutez is the minimum possible balance

3) different allocation pools, early backers are explicitly encoded, contributors to the fundraiser represented as commitments

4) it's the other way around, when a blake2b hash of the tz1 address, keyed with an activation code, is taken, it should match the commitment address. Activation codes are included in blocks as an operation.

Comment: Thanks Arthur! Much appreciated.